# Is this expression for Loss valid?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, dropout, log-loss

The negative likelihood loss over training set $t$ where a training instance is given by $x^{(t)}$, taget by $y^{(t)}$, a specific masking (dropout) by $m$ and weights by $w$ as:

$$L(w|m) = -\sum_t log(P(y^{(t)}|x^{(t)},m,w))$$

My only problem is that in the LHS $w$ is conditioned over $m$ but in the right hand both $w$ and $m$ are in the conditional.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say by writing $L(w|m)$?

Comment: @Tim right forgot to write the log

Comment: I rather meant the left hand side, what do you mean by conditional loss?